# Import takeUntill from Rxjs Angular 13 and allowedCommonJsDependencies array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem with rxjs (v6) and commmonJsDependencies.

I try to import takeUntil and append JSDependeciy to angular.json allowedCommonJsDependencies array.

All the time I see an error:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/d/angular/node_modules/rxjs/operators' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/d/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs
Did you mean to import rxjs/operators/index.js
```

I have tried with:

1. `import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs';`
2. `import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';`
3. `import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/index';`

and allowedCommonJsDependencies:

1. rxjs
2. rxjs/operators
3. rxjs/operators/index

what should be in .ts file and in the config .json file?

edit:
I use es2015

src/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

"@angular/animations": "13.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^13.0.3",
"@angular/common": "13.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "13.1.0",
"@angular/core": "13.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "13.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "13.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.1.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "13.1.0",
"@angular/router": "13.1.0",

"rxjs": "6.6.7",
"typescript": "4.4.4"

even if I got rid off every `rxjs/operators`, I still have the same error: `rxjs/operators' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from ...`

(I replaced `rxjs/operators` with `rxjs/internal/operators`)

Comment: You don't need to add `rxjs` to the angular.json, or did you add something else?

Comment: @Batajus I want to add a module to angular.json because of [link]https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
Without this declaration I see a warning (it's just a warning but maybe it's better to get rid of it): `/my-component.component.ts depends on 'rxjs/operators/index'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.`

Comment: I see this warning with simple ng serve, but when I run ssr, then I see `Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/d/angular/node_modules/rxjs/operators' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/d/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs
Did you mean to import rxjs/operators/index.js`

Comment: Can you share your Angular and Typescript versions and potentially your tsconfig.json

Comment: @Batajus sure, I updated a issue description

Answer (score 1):

The only solution in my case was to upgrade RXJS to 7.4.